# Hosting a Web Server and Web Service locally on same port

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, localhost, hosting, gulp

I seem to miss somehting really obvious.
Anyways, i am developing a ReactJs web app and use nodejs (browser-sync) to host a simple web server for testing on localhost. Everything's working fine.

As for the server side i have a REST Service hosted in ASP.NET WebAPI.

I want to keep the urls in the web app relative for deployment reasons (because then it doesn't matter what the hostname is, as long it's running on the same domain).

I know out of experience that it's possible to host a self hosted ASP.NET WebAPI and a Web Application in IIS Express (at least in different paths) at the same time.

But now when i start browser-sync (which uses node http server internally as far as i can tell) and then WebAPI service host, the service host tells me it can't host on this url.

When i start it the other way around, browser-sync automatically increases the port so that it's on the next free port.

Does somebody have experience with it?

**EDIT:**

My question maybe in a more general sense: How do you develop web apps that are hosted on a local web server (in my case via nodejs) against a local running web service? And do you use relative URLs in your web app? Which leads to the problem that the service and the web have to run on the same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

- ASP.NET WebAPI hosts under a different port then the nodejs web server
- I set up a proxy in nodejs webserver for all urls starting with '/api/' and proxy these requests to the WebAPI port
- I can use relative URLs in my client

Comment: This is how you can do it using http-server serving just static files, given 8080 is the port you want to browse the site and 8081 is the site your API web server is running: `http-server -o -p 8080 -P http://localhost:8081/`